# I have a list of IDs, each of which is again associated with several IDS and some values. How to code in python to save this data?

Tags: python

I am reading in data of the following type from a file, and I need a method to store it for further calculations.

ID1    ,      ID2       ,    value

A      ,      1         ,     520

A      ,      2         ,      180

A      ,      3         ,      80

B      ,      1         ,      49

C      ,      1        ,       96

C       ,     2          ,     287

etc.

What is the best way to save it?

In PERL, I would have used a hash and separators, as follows, and then called by hash key and separated using split over the comma:

$data{$ID1} .= $ID2.':'.$value.',';

I have to address the following problem in PYTHON as it would be integrated with other code, but I am new to the language. Please suggest what might be the best way to do it.

P.S. The input data file is huge (~500Mb) and could be more.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have a look at the `pickle` module

Answer (score 0):

If you've loaded your data with Python, and your next program down the line is also written in Python, you can simply use the `pickle` module, like this:

```
big_list_list = [["A", 1, 520], ["A", 2, 180], ["B", 1, 49]]

import pickle

# Storing the data
with open("data.pickle", "wb") as outfile:
    pickle.dump(big_list_list, outfile)

# Retrieving the data
with with open("data.pickle", "rb") as infile:
    reconstructed_big_list_list = pickle.load(infile)
```

This has two caveats: if part of your workflow includes Non-Python programs, they won't be able to read pickles. And you shouldn't trust pickle files from arbitrary sources, since they could contain malicious code.

Instead of using pickles, you can also use JSON files. Simple replace the word `pickle` with `json` in the recipy above. JSON has the advantage that many Non-Python programs can deal with it.

Even more universal would be the use of CSV files, like this:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(big_list_list)

with open('data.csv', newline='') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    reconstructed_big_list_list = [row for row in reader]
```

Python's standard library also includes the module `sqlite3`, which allows you to write your data to a database, which might be useful if your data becomes more complicated than a simple list of lists, or you need concurrent access.

PS.: I just saw that you noted that your files could be uge. In this case, you could modify the CSV solution to store and load your data incrementally:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in big_list_list:
        writer.writerow(row)

with open('data.csv', newline='') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```